# using upsert in array search in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am working on mongodb and making a database structure as:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e9fef05c0228a50befba0d7"),
        "name" : "sanghm",
        "id" : "3456",
        "dep" : {
                "dep1" : "ops",
                "dep2" : "analytics"
        },
        "data" : [
                {
                        "date" : "25-apr-2020",
                        "log" : [

                                {
                                        "machine" : "windows-user1",
                                        "task" : "excel",
                                          "time": "10:00am"
                                }
                                {
                                        "machine" : "windows-user1",
                                        "task" : "email",
                                          "time": "11:00am"
                                }

                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

to push every new task on database, i'm using a query like

```
date = '25-apr-2020'

db.inventory.update({id:'3456'},{{$push:{'data.$[t].log':{machine:'windows-user1',task:'new task',time:'3:00pm'}}},{arrayFilters:[{"t.date":date}]}})
```

this query pushing new task to date array.
if in case the date changes to '26-apr-2020' then can we use same query to first add new date filed and then push data for the same.

i have read about `{upsert: true}` but dont know how  to use it in my case

Answer (score 0):

The double nesting is weird. Usually all of the events would be stored flat in the top level `data` array and one would produce the grouping by date (if desired) at query time.